# Failed to convert value of type java.lang.Long to String - Android Studio - Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm coding a Tic Tac Toe, and while executing it crashes when I tried to read a value from the database.

I'm getting the following error:

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.lang.Long to String

The line where it crashes is the following : `canPlay = Long.parseLong(snapshot.getValue(String.class));`

The function is the following:

```
refPeutJouer.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        peutjouer = Long.parseLong(snapshot.getValue(String.class));
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {}
});
```

The variable is declared as `private long peutjouer` at the beginning of the class.
I have declared the `DatabaseReference` as follows: `private DatabaseReference refPeutJouer = database.getReference("peutJouer");`

Here is a screenshot of the Firebase database:

[image: Screenshot of the Database]

I tried to switch from an int to a long, but that didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `peutJouer` property in the screenshot you shared is a numeric value. The code you use to read it however does:

```
snapshot.getValue(String.class)
```

Since the snapshot does not have a `String` value, you can't retrieve it like that.

Instead, you'll want to extract is with:

```
peutjouer = snapshot.getValue(Long.class);
```